# Simple way to revert .orig files?

Tags: mercurial

I've just gone and accidentally run `hg revert *`. Does Mercurial come with a tool to move all the `.orig` files back into place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  If you're in bash you can always do:

```
for thefile in *.orig ; do cp -v $thefile ${thefile%%.orig} ; done
```

Comment: And in Windows command prompt with Command Extensions enabled, you can do `for /f %i in ('dir /s /b *.orig') do @copy %i %~dpni`

Comment: @leoger: Wow… That basically looks like line noise to me. I guess that's how non-programmers feel when they see shell…

Comment: @david: it looks like line noise to me too! I had to do `help for` to look up the variable slicing operators :) d for drive, p for path, n for name (as opposed to name plus file extension)

Comment: Here's one that'll do your whole tree (ie recurse into your folders) `find . -name "*.orig" | while read f; do cp -v $f ${f%%.orig}; done`

Comment: This will only work if the .orig files are in the directory you run the command in. My answer below should work for all *.orig files in the repo regardless of where you run it.

Comment: So does s29's in the comment above.

Answer (score 4):

This command will reinstate your .orig files from anywhere inside your repo:

```
find `hg root` -name *.orig -exec rename -f 's/.orig//' {} \;
```

You can add a hg alias for this in your .hgrc like so:

```
[alias]
reinstate= !find `$HG root` -name *.orig -exec rename -f 's/.orig//' {} \;
```

And then run it from your repo using this command:

```
hg reinstate
```

Comment: you can also add `-v` to the rename command to see the renamed files

Comment: FYI, I needed to wrap the `*.orig` in quotes to prevent the shell from trying to expand that star.

Answer (score 0):

No, but your operating system probably provides `cp` command (or equivalent). Just copy .orig onto reverted file, or, if you've commited the file in the wanted version, revert it again from that version.

Comment: Right, I'm just trying to avoid doing that for 15 files…