# How to undo a revert in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, revert

After I had accidentally added several files with

```
hg add
```

I wanted to revert that with

```
hg revert --all
```

Unfortunatelly I hadn't committed my intended changes so they were reverted as well. Can I get that content back?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You did not specify the `--no-backup`, so there should be backup files right next to the actual file.

[Documentation to support this](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revert)

> Modified files are saved with a .orig suffix before reverting. To disable these backups, use --no-backup.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a way to tell mercurial to restore those .orig files?

Comment: Just move them back on top of the original, using either a command prompt move command, or your systems file manager.

Comment: I think what BandGap was asking, is if hg provides a command to restore the backup (without any commandline-fu or manual copying).

Comment: @s29 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464585/mercurial-simple-way-to-revert-orig-files for that answer

Comment: @BangGap here is a command to "restore your hg backup"-- `find . -name "*.orig" | while read f; do cp -v $f ${f%%.orig}; done`