# Undoing a revert in mercurial (not a duplicate query)

Tags: mercurial, revert

I have a mercurial repo with no uncommitted changes. I was on revision 846, and decided my last 2 commits were junk and wanted to carry on as if from revision 844. So I was going to type:

```
hg revert -r 844 --all
```

Unfortunately I mistyped, and wrote:

```
hg revert -r 44 --all
```

So my whole repository has changed dramatically, including directory structure. I don't see any .orig files, so I don't think the answer in:

[How to undo a revert in mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527125/how-to-undo-a-revert-in-mercurial)

helps me.

hg log still has all of my commits up to revision 846 - do you think I can revert back to revision 846?

Advice very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg revert` just sets your working copy to the revision that you specify so if you didn't do a commit after the revert then your repository has not changed.  To fix it you can just do `hg update -C` and then delete all the `.orig` files.

After that you can do the correct revert statement to remove the last two revisions.

If you did do the commit then the command that you wanted to do (`hg revert -r 844 --all`) would still get you to the point that you want by undoing the revert commit as well as the two commits that you originally intended to undo.

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't commit, I noticed the problem as soon as I hit <return>, thankfully. Can I ask, why the "-C" in update? I'm digging around the mercurial manual/book/website and can't find a clear statement of what it is for. If I did "hg update", that would take me to the current head, which is revision 846, which is what I want. I can find references to -C being used for named branches, which seems irrelevant?

Comment: `hg update -C` discards uncommitted changes and I wouldn't have thought that it would have worked without it.  It certainly didn't work in my tests.

Comment: I didn't have any uncommitted changes - maybe that's why? When I say it worked - I ended up with a working directory that matched my expectations. I also had a bunch of .orig files, and (more confusingly) I had a whole load of old files in their old locations without .orig. So I had to do some cleaning up. Is that consistent with your expectations and tests?

Comment: Yes, it seemed like it didn't really work and you cleaned it up manually. :)  You should have had uncommitted changes because you changed your working copy to be the same as revision 44 and those changes were uncommitted.