# Windows Shell. Restoring Orig Files

Tags: powershell, mercurial, cmd

After a quick google search I found this link: [Mercurial: simple way to revert .orig files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464585/mercurial-simple-way-to-revert-orig-files), with the following line of code in the comment:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /s /b *.orig') do @copy %i %~dpni
```

In powershell, I tried running it, but I got the following error: `Missing opening ( after kyeword for`.

Is powershell not the correct way to run this code or is the syntax incorrect?

I am trying to revert my orig files back to their original version (get rid of the .orig extension). I am using windows so BASH is not an easy option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment that snippet came from suggests that the environment you can run that line in is the "Windows command prompt with Command Extensions."

You can create that environment like so: `cmd /e:on`.  It didn't seem like using powershell was the intention, but you could type `cmd /e:on` into the powershell console and get that environment.

```
PS C:\> cmd /e:on
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>  Command Prompt Input is Valid Here
```

You received that error because that syntax is incorrect for powershell -- `for` statements expect parameters in parenthesis.  It should work once you're in the appropriate shell, though.